# Typescript angular controller constructor does not execute

Tags: angularjs, typescript

After this line of code runs

```
    cockpit.controller('shell', shellCtrl);
```

in my main module, the shell controller is registered with the angular application's _invokeQueue, but the code in the shellCtrl's constructor never fires.  Why wouldn't it?

Here is the TypeScript for shellCtrl

```
module cockpit {
'use strict';

export class shellCtrl {
    public static $inject = [
        '$location', '$rootScope', '$scope',
        'localize'
    ];
    public userId = 0;

    constructor($location, $rootScope, $scope, localize) {
        $scope.vm = this;

        $rootScope.$on('localizeResourcesUpdated', function () {
            $rootScope.title = localize.getLocalizedString('_appTitle_');
        });
        //If the userid is null go to login
        if (this.userId == 0) {
            $location.path('/login');
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Not sure what the scope is exactly here, but `shellCtrl` is only available with the scope of `cockpit` or directly: `cockpit.shellCtrl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke it from html. Basically you need `ng-controller="shell"` based on your code.

PS: I have a detailed video on the subject : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdtVn_8K17E&hd=1

Comment: I have ng-controller = shell in the view.  Actually shell.html is ng-included to index.html but that should work out the same.  But even if I didn't have the controller referenced, shouldn't the code in the constructor fire when the object is instantiated?  BTW, that is an excellent video.  Thank you.

Comment: The controller will not be instantiated unless it is requested

Comment: Now, I see that.  The problem turns out to be that angular can't find the controller when it goes to bind it to the scope, even though I can see it loaded in the DOM.

Comment: Nice approach explained in the youtube video. It's as close to idiomatic TypeScript as you can get.

Comment: You also need to register the controller: angular.module("myModule").controller("shell", shellCtrl);